# Not able to change the colour of a KMZ layer in QGIS

Tags: polygon, layers, kmz

I have a question about the kmz files. I've been using QGIS for some time now, and I've always dragged and dropped the files into QGIS. Now I tried that and a window popped asking me which layer I wanted to add to my project.

[image]

Once selected the layer it appears the outline of the polygon, and in the layers the file appears with the polygon symbol instead of the colored square

[image]

I'm not able to change the colour and that stuff in the properties

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

A KMZ layer can contain its own style. Therefore, in Layer Style Panel, you will see the style type as `Embedded Symbols`. You must change this setting to apply your own style.

Open "Layer Styling (F7)" panel. Change `Embedded Symbols` to another one, `Single Symbol` for example.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On the `Layers pane`, right-click on the kmz polygon layer you added, select `Properties`, and go to the `Symbology` vertical tab. On the top-most drop-down list, select `Single Symbol`, then select the symbology you want to use.